# SQL search can not return result if one word is right and another is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In my website, there is a search box where a user gives input and search that word whether it is in the mySQL database or not.

My code :

```
$search_text = $_POST['srch-text'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE content LIKE '%$search_text%';";

$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
$number_of_results = $result->num_rows;
```

It is working fine if anyone inputs two words which are existed in database.
Suppose anyone gives inputs "ABCD XYZ". Here ABCD exists in database but XYZ does not exist in database. Then it returns no result. I want to show the result of ABCD word.

Comment: Replace spaces on the input with a `%` sign.

Comment: @WEI_DBA replacing the space with `%` would still require both parts of the string to be present and be in the same order to get a match, which is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: @cteski Ah.. .I see... my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.  If you are using spaces to separate words, then you need to replace them with `|`:

```
SELECT *
FROM search
WHERE content REGEXP REPLACE(?, ' ', '|');
```

You should also be passing the string in using parameters, rather than munging the query string with user input.  That is why this example uses `?` as a placeholder for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use regex, I would use php's [`explode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to create an array, and then either do multiple sql queries or [`implode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with `%` as the "glue".

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string into two strings with space ' ' as separator
Here is a sql script which you easily convert into mysql

```
declare @s as varchar(100)
declare @s1 as varchar(100)
declare @s2 as varchar(100)

set @s='STRING1 STRING2'
declare @n as int
set @n=charindex(' ',@s)
if @n>0 
begin
set @s1=substring(@s,1,@n-1)
set @s2=substring(@s,@n+1,len(@s))
end

select @s1 [mystring1],@s2[mystring2]
```

Then replace you query instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE content LIKE '%$search_text%';";
```

by

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE content LIKE '%'+@string1+'%' or content LIKE '%'+@string1+'%'
```

Here is the equivalent mysql script

```
set @s='STRING1 STRING2';

set @n=LOCATE(' ',@s,1);

set @s1=substring(@s,1,@n-1);
set @s2=substring(@s,@n+1,LENGTH(@s));


select @s1 "mystring1",@s2"mystring2";
```